# App Barcode Scanners

Tags: java, android, api, barcode-scanner

I'm going out on a bit of a limb here asking this but I'm struggling to find any information  about this anywhere.

I have built an app with a barcode reader and it works in that it reads the barcode and displays the result. But the result is just the barcode number which we can already see.  I want to build it so that it will read the barcode and then give me product information.

I've heard about APIs and how Amazon have one but I can't find out anywhere how to go about this.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just google the UPC and you'll get product info, or use any of the UPC, EAN lookup sites.

Comment: can you provide a sample barcode with which you are testing the application?

Comment: @ViVekH it's any barcode I scan. I particularly want to be able to scan electrical items like laptops, etc

Comment: Assuming you built a barcode scanner, when you scan it will read the information from the barcode which in your case is the barcode number, IF you want additional information you need to have a server or some infrastructure to query and return information(like items) related to the scanned barcode.

Comment: @ViVekH "it will read the information from the barcode which in your case is the barcode number" This is true for any case. A barcode by design only contains a number. Nothing else.

Comment: How can I integrate an API into my scanner?  I don't know if I'm searching for the right answers but I can't seem to find anything anywhere that will help me with that

Answer (score 3):

Scanning a barcode only gives you the bar code number. The barcode does not inherently contain any data about the product. You need another source for that information. However, once you have the barcode you can just lookup the data from a Google search or some sort of database.